# Fastest case insensitive search

Tags: javascript

In my works, I was doing .toLowerCase() on everything, this resulted in .toLowerCase() running on the same string many times as it loops through different stuff.

Someone told me to cach the toLowerCase'd string instead of doing that. Another said use Regex, I wrote a a jsperf test, but what prompted me to post asking here, is doing `.search` with `new RegExp(needle, 'i')` versus `/hay/i` created great speed difference.

What is the accepted way for most performant case insensitive indexOf?

Here is my jsPerf: http://jsperf.com/fastest-case-insensitive-indexof

Comment: it would be about the same if you declared the literal out-of-band; making objects is expensive... the speedup is from re-using the same RegExp object for each test, instead of having to make a new one each test...

Comment: indexOf is a lot faster than  RegExp methods (any of them), so if you can recycle a cached lowerCase version of the haystack and needle, that should be the quickest.

Comment: Thanks very much @dandavis I'll add that test case :)

Comment: Ah you're write, the .indexOf method blows it out of the water! Thanks @dandavis

Comment: see my test in chrome, exec with fresh patt but diff syntax is much more faster

Comment: Very intersting thank you @user1465639